# Efficient construction of a formal polynomial using list manipulations

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming

I have a code which is probably extremely inefficient given my inexperience with Mathematica list manipulation. Take as input data:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[m_, n_] := 
  Select[LessEqualThan[1 + n]@*Max@*Counts]@*
    Map[Apply[Sequence]@*IntegerPartitions]@*Range@m;
PS1[m_, n_] := 
  DeleteCases[
   Tuples[{f[m, n], f[m, n]}], {a_, b_} /; Length[a] != Length[b]];
PS[m_, n_] := Prepend[PS1[m, n], {{}, {}}];
```

For what it's worth, `PS[m,n]` is a possibly very large list of all pairs of integer partitions satisfying some conditions. I'm happy with this part of my code. I want to use this list to produce a polynomial in formal variables $Q, p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n}$. My code here is:

```
Format[p[m_, n_]] := Subscript[p, m]^n;
m = 7;
n = 3;
p[0, 1] = 1;
p[n + 1, 1] = 1;
TestPolynomial[K_, Q_] := 
  Sum[Q^{Total[PS[m, n][[i]][[1]] + PS[m, n][[i]][[2]]] - 
       Length[PS[m, n][[i]][[1]]]}*
    Product[(1 - Q^{j})^{n + 1}*p[Count[PS[m, n][[i]][[1]], j], 1]*
      p[n + 1 - Count[PS[m, n][[i]][[2]], j], 1], {j, 1, K}], {i, 1, 
    Length[PS[m, n]]}];

SeriesCoefficient[TestPolynomial[20,Q][[1]],{Q,0,5}]
```

Even for these small $n,m$ this takes an very long time to compute. I'm hoping someone has advice on speeding up this code. As you can probably see, I'm summing over `PS[m,n]` with a nested finite product on the inside. The formal variables in a sense measure the number of times an integer appears in these partitions.  Hence, all the guys like `Count[PS[m, n][[i]][[1]], j]`.

I would love if it were possible to speed this up so that for $n,m$ more or less in the range $(1,60)$, this were fairly quick to compute. But perhaps that is just not possible.